# Proof that $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(m,n-k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I need to show that for $m,n,k\in \mathbb{Z}$, $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m,n\neq 0$:
\begin{equation}
\label{1}\tag{1}\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(m,n-k)
\end{equation}

The proof begins with stating that
$$
d=\gcd(m,n) \Rightarrow m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}=d\mathbb{Z}<\mathbb{Z}
$$
which I get. I also understand why
$$
m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}= m\mathbb{Z}+(n-km)\mathbb{Z}<\mathbb{Z}
$$
What I do not understand is, why this last step is sufficient in showing \eqref{1}. I thank you in advance.

**Edit :** I am pretty sure now with your help that the book has typo there. It was meant to show that $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(m,n-km)$. For all interested in the proof still and where the idea comes from, just a little background.

To find the gcd of $n_1,...n_r \in\mathbb{Z}$ we use the homomorphism
$$
h: \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times...\times\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z},\, \, h(x_1,...,x_r)=x_1n_1+..x_rn_r
$$
and the fact that
$$
\text{im}(h)=\langle n_1,...n_2 \rangle <\mathbb{Z}
$$
so since it is a subgroup there is a $d \in\mathbb{Z}$ with $\text{im}(h)=d\mathbb{Z}$. Since all $n_i$ are in $\text{im}(h)$, $d$ is a common divisor of all $n_i$ and also $d\in \text{im}(f)$, so there are $x_1,...,x_r$ with $d=x_1n_1+...+x_rn_r$. If $y$ is another common divisor of $n_1,...n_r$ then $y$ is also a divisor because of $d=x_1n_1+...+x_rn_r$, so $d\geq y$. So we can define $\gcd(n_1,...,n_r):=d$.

Comment: Where is $l$ and what is $k$?

Comment: certainly isn't true for any $k$...

Comment: @Andronicus: I am sorry, thank you for pointing that out. I wrote l instead of k.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain: True, I edited it. Thank you and sorry.

Comment: you still seem to be missing something, should it be $n-km$ instead of $n-k$?

Comment: You need some condition on $k$ or the result is false. For example, take $m=4,n=8$. Then $\gcd(m,n)=4$. If $k=1$, then $\gcd(m,n-k=\gcd(4,7)=1\ne4$.

Comment: you are right and that is weird because it states no condition for $k$ in the book. my guess would be that it is assumed that $k>1$.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain, no the book really says $n-k$... but the weird thing is that when it shows the euklidian algorithm, it uses that $n-km$ as does the proof. maybe a typo?

Comment: Other books I checked also only show that $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(m,n-km)$ or $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(m,n+km)$ so I would assume that it is a typo.

Comment: $n-km$ would make this a true statement and an interesting proof.

Comment: I am pretty sure now that it is a typo and $n-km$ is meant.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I just gave a bit of background information about the proof.

Comment: I am not sure why $n-km$ would be what is meant though. The proof is trivial at that point using basic properties of divisibility. Very confusing indeed why such a proof would be used for a result like this.